# MVVM Editable ComboBox without changing the SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-core-3.1

I have exactly the same requirements as this user: [MVVM Editable ComboBox Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479093/mvvm-editable-combobox-bindings).

I've tried the accepted answer:

> "Bind a property like "EditedServerName" to Combobox.Text. When the
> "EditedServerName" is changed you can set the value to the
> "ServerName" of your SelectedServer."

But it's not working because when I try to intercept "EditedServerName" the "SelectedServer" is null. I believe it's because the control tries to search the "ServerName" that is being edited, in the collection, and obviously fails to retrieve an element. This is very clear when I start editing and the textblock with the "ServerID" just gets immediately empty.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable= "True" 
            ItemsSource= "{Binding Servers}"
            DisplayMemberPath= "ServerName"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServer}"
            Text= "{Binding EditedServerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedServer.ServerID}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public List<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public Server SelectedServer { get; set; }

    private string editedServerName;
    public string EditedServerName
    {
        get { return editedServerName; }
        set 
        { 
            editedServerName = value;
            SelectedServer.ServerName = value;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Servers = new List<Server>();
        Servers.Add(new Server { ServerID = 0, ServerName = "Local" });
        Servers.Add(new Server { ServerID = 1, ServerName = "Remote" });
    }
```

I know I could temporarily store the "SelectedServer" on another object, but I would like a better turn-around if possible.

Comment: Are you able to paste your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: @Hayden I've tried my best to improve the question. I hope this is now clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your `MainViewModel` is not making proper use of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which is recommended for data binding back to the view. This is the reason that there's no change to the UI with your currently posted code.
2. You're correct in saying that once the `EditedServerName` is changed, the `SelectedServer` will become *null*, but with point 1, it's getting to that point either. Even if we fix the code to accommodate data binding, the `SelectedServer` property is not handling *null*.

With that in mind, here's what the code might look like if we modify the code to accommodate the above points:

*Below code helps notify the view of any changes to our Models / ViewModels*

```
public class BaseNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

*Here's what our updated model looks like. Note the use of `OnPropertyChanged` which is defined in `BaseNotifier`, as this will update the View with the new server name*

```
public class Server : BaseNotifier
{
    private string _serverName;

    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _serverName; }
        set
        {
            _serverName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _serverID;

    public int ServerID
    {
        get { return _serverID; }
        set
        {
            _serverID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

*This is what the ViewModel now looks like. For ViewModels, use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` to allow autmatic view updates when inserting data. You'll also notice that the code checks for null in both the SelectedServer and EditedServerName which should handle your original question.*

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseNotifier
{
    private string editedServerName;
    private Server selectedServer = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public Server SelectedServer
    {
        get { return selectedServer; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedServer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string EditedServerName
    {
        get { return editedServerName; }
        set
        {
            editedServerName = value;

            if (SelectedServer != null)
            {
                SelectedServer.ServerName = value;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Servers = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
        Servers.Add(new Server { ServerID = 0, ServerName = "Local" });
        Servers.Add(new Server { ServerID = 1, ServerName = "Remote" });
    }
}
```