# Combobox does not update SelectedItem if the Item is not in the itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have the following idea to implement. Basically I have a list of countries and their abbreviations.
I want to display them in a combobox and offer the features autocomplete, autoreplace and free inputs.
This shows what I've built so far (just a small example to show what I mean. The full code is longer):

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox
        Width="200"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"                                    
        SelectedItem="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"           
        ItemsSource="{Binding TestList, Mode=OneTime}"
        >           
    </ComboBox>        
</Grid>
```

The Viewmodel looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Test1
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        public List<string> TestList { get; set; }

        private string _testString;

        public string TestString
        {
            get => _testString;
            set =>SetField(ref _testString, value);
        }


        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            TestList = new List<string>() { "Hello", "World", "From", "WPF" };
        }


    }
}
```

The Problem I am having is basically twofold:

If I input a value that is not in the `Itemsource` the `selectedItem` becomes `null` and my Setter receives null as well. That is problematic because in the setter I would like to implement the replace logic and I theoretically need the value in case the user puts in a country that is not in my list.
I found a way to partially help me in my problem by setting `Text="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` in my Combobox as well. This leads to me hitting the setter twice. One Time with the value and one time without. The problem with this idea should be clear: hitting it twice should not be necessary and secondly when I get a useable value to do my replacement logic the Combobox does not update (even though I do call PropertyChanged on the replaced string).

Therefore I'd like to know if there is a root cause for these two problems that would lead to fixing them both?

Comment: Problematic  or not, this is how the `ComboBox` works. You cannot select a value that's not in the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: So basically my only option is to write my own?

Comment: Will this helps you in some direction?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479093/mvvm-editable-combobox-bindings

Comment: @Brezelmann: Yes. Or use another (third-party) control.

Comment: @mm8 do you have one in mind that could solve my problem in particular?

Comment: @Brezelmann: No, I am afraid I haven't.

Comment: @GK It is similar but I have a subtle difference that makes this idea probably not work: I don't have full fledged objects but strings and my combobox is bound to a list of strings as well. This leads to the fact that I can receive both values by setting my string to receive both from selectedItem and Text but I cannot communicate to the combobox that my value I received by text is replaced with a value that is in the list. Eg I type in DE and tab out of the box. In my Viewmodel I receive the info and change DE to Germany and fire the event. Germany is in the list of items but no update occurs